# What is the difference between ImageView.getMatrix() and ImageView.getImageMatrix()?

Tags: android

I've seen this question asked in different forums, but no one ever gave an answer. Does getMatrix deal with the images position within the view while getImageMatrix deals with the size of the image relative to itself?

**Edit:**

Here are what the docs say:

> **Matrix getImageMatrix ()**
>
> Return the view's optional matrix. This is applied to the view's drawable when it is drawn. If there is no matrix, this method will return an identity matrix. Do not change this matrix in place but make a copy. If you want a different matrix applied to the drawable, be sure to call setImageMatrix().

.

> **Matrix getMatrix ()**
>
> The transform matrix of this view, which is calculated based on the current rotation, scale, and pivot properties.

Comment: What's the documentation say?

Comment: Also, `getMatrix` is for all view objects, not just `ImageView`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[getMatrix()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getMatrix()) returns matrix that you can use to manipulate the view itself, translate, rotate, scaled or skew the view. It is method of `View` class. While [getImageMatrix()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#getImageMatrix()) returns matrix for manipulating drawable inside `ImageView` and it is declared in `ImageView` class.

Comment: Another important difference is that the ImageView matrix can be changed (use setImageMatrix() to apply the new one), while the matrix coming from View.getMatrix() is read-only property. If you want to manipulate the view, you cannot simply change this matrix. You must use View.setPivotXY, View.setRotationXY, and View.setScaleXY.

Comment: @AlexCohn Thanks for pointing this out. Have a doubt - wouldn't view.getMatrix().set(matrix) have the same effect as view.setMatrix() - if there was a method setMatrix() ?